# rename index or homepage

Tags: multisite, homepage

I've tried about anything but I can't seem to get it to work how I would like to so I hope you can help me out.

Situation. 
I have 2 wordpress websites, running on different hosts, only link is a 'commercial' links.
they are set up like this.
url.com/wp is my wordpress directory, with my index in root. referring. 
So I have pretty url url.com/contact etc.

Now I have a simple html page which has to be a selector. When you go to url.com and url2.com you see this index.html which links to url.com and url2.com.

so each root page of the urls , the user can choose to go to url 1 or 2.

I can't change my hostings first file to go to, to take index.htm before the index.php of wordpress. .htacces using DirectoryIndex  didnt do the trick either.

So I would like to rename my index.php from wordpress to something else. But then it just breaks...

I hope I'm clear enough about it. It's a 'simple' problem but kind of hard to explain for me.

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a loop that you can't break out of ... I think what you are saying is you want a visitor to go to

`domain1.com/index.html` 
and then choose to go to
`domain1.com/index.php`  (Wordpress CMS) or
`domain2.com/index.php`

**Static Homepage in WordPress**
You're best off to create a Static Homepage in WordPress and have links on this to either    `domain1.com/what_ever_page_is_your_blog`

You can also create your own [custom landing page template](http://wordpress.damien.co/2010/03/wordpress-use-a-custom-design-for-landing-pages-2/) which is then published from inside WordPress.

**Move all Wordpress files including index.php to sub-folder**
The easier approach would be to just move all the wordpress files into a sub-folder like
`domain1.com/wordpress`

This way you can have visitor go to

`domain1.com/index.html` and chose to go to
`domain1.com/wordpress`  or
`domain2.com`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your first suggestion. Second is my last resort, but I don't want my pages to be domain1.com/wordpress/contact or ../page , but directly domain1.com/contact or /page

Comment: Ok , great. Because of your comment I found a solution, I have no idea why I didn't think of this before. I made a template file for the start selection and put this as static homepage, so i could give the actual homepage a slug. thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thats a great idea too ... create your own page-template.php file and then you just add a page using this template in your first blog. Thanks